# Bash, splitting string fail

Tags: arrays, string, bash, split

Following what I found here, I tried to split the list of files of a certain pattern to an array. However, the string doesn't split (The empty line is just to ease on the reading).

```
bash-3.2$ files=jfn240_463.o*
bash-3.2$ echo $files
jfn240_463.o9017306 jfn240_463.o9075989 jfn240_463.o9281439 jfn240_463.o9287196

bash-3.2$ IFS=' ' read -ra ll <<< $files
bash-3.2$ echo $ll
jfn240_463.o9017306 jfn240_463.o9075989 jfn240_463.o9281439 jfn240_463.o9287196

bash-3.2$ IFS=' ' read -ra ll <<< "$files"
bash-3.2$ echo $ll
jfn240_463.o9017306 jfn240_463.o9075989 jfn240_463.o9281439 jfn240_463.o9287196

bash-3.2$ echo ${ll[@]}
jfn240_463.o9017306 jfn240_463.o9075989 jfn240_463.o9281439 jfn240_463.o9287196

bash-3.2$ echo ${ll[1]}

bash-3.2$
```

I was sure I would get an array, so why won't I?

Edit:

I tried to use `find` instead without much success.

```
bash-3.2$ files=$(find jfn240_463.o*)
bash-3.2$ echo ${files[0]}
jfn240_463.o9017306 jfn240_463.o9075989 jfn240_463.o9281439 jfn240_463.o9287196
bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ IFS=' ' read -ra ll <<< $files
bash-3.2$ echo ${ll[@]}
jfn240_463.o9017306
bash-3.2$
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `$files` contains `"jfn240_463.o*"` and *not* a bunch of filenames delimited by spaces. You can't split that by a space since there's no space even in it. Use an array in the first place:

```
ll=(jfn240_463.o*)
```

Comment: So how do I achieve this? I tried to use ``find`` and failed (updated my question).

Answer (score 0):

[Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) has the problem precisely correct: when you define:

```
$ files=jfn240_463.o*
```

the shell does *not* expand the `*` ("pathname expansion"). When you write:

```
$ echo $files
```

the shell *does* expand the `*`. To see the real value of `$files`, you need to write:

```
$ echo "$files"
jfn240_463.o*
```

So `$files` does not have a space in it.

You might expect the same to apply to `<<<`, but it turns out that bash does not distinguish between `<<<$files` and `<<<"$files"`, because bash does not do pathname expansion on the word following `<<<`. You can see this by typing, for example:

```
$ cat <<<jfn240_463.o*
jfn240_463.o*
```

(There is actually a small difference between `<<<$files` and `<<<"$files"`. Bash performs parameter expansion, command expansion and arithmetic expansion on the word following `<<<`, in this case `$files`. If the word is not quoted, it also performs word-splitting. However, after the word-splitting is finished, the words are joined together again, separated by a single space. Consequently, in the unquoted case, all sequences of whitespace are reduced to a single space, whereas in the quoted case the white space is retained precisely. The difference is most visible when `$IFS` has been changed to something other than whitespace.)

There are various possible workarounds, of which the simplest is to simply set the array directly, as Ignacio Vasquez-Abrams suggests:

```
ll=(jfn240_463.o*)
```

(In this syntax, bash *does* perform pathname expansion.)

However, that will fail if any file has whitespace in its name. Another simple solution (with bash), if no file has a newline in its name, is to use mapfile:

```
mapfile -t ll < <(ls jfn240_463.o*)
```

or, with the bash builtin printf:

```
mapfile -t ll < <(printf "%s\n" jfn240_463.o*)
```

It's by no means simple to get this to work in the case where a filename might contain arbitrary characters (other than `\0` and `/`, which cannot appear in filenames).